# How to convert CStyle cast to c++, Unsigned Char to LPCSTR

Tags: c++

I'm trying to change the C Style cast of (LPCSTR) to a static_cast, but I get "Invalid type conversion".

```
unsigned char buffer[81];

...

HWND hdlg = this->GetSafeHwnd();
SetDlgItemTextA(hdlg, IDC_EDIT_REQUEST, (LPCSTR)buffer);
```

I've tried the following but both show "Invalid type conversion"

```
SetDlgItemTextA(hdlg, IDC_EDIT_REQUEST, static_cast<LPCSTR>(buffer));
SetDlgItemTextA(hdlg, IDC_EDIT_REQUEST, static_cast<char const*>(buffer));
```

What is the correct why to static_cast an unsigned char to LPCSTR ?

Comment: You *can’t* perform this conversion via `static_cast`. You need to use `reinterpret_cast`. If, for some reason, you don’t want to do that, your only option is to create a new buffer and to *copy* the buffer over character for character.

Comment: `staic_cast` can't be used to convert between unrelated types

Comment: That will not be good enough. You need to convert from char to wide character string too. Have a look at microsofts documentation (maybe you need older A2W conversion utilities) :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/87zae4a3(v=vs.120)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I'm intentionally calling the `A` version of the Microsoft `SetDlgItemTextA`, so that I didn't need to convert the character string

Comment: I see now that you did... sorry years of working with LPWSTR (in the past) ;)
LPCSTR is indeed just a `const char*` (I checked windows.h).
So your code should work : https://godbolt.org/z/vnsedWqsr.

I always used to use SetDlgItemText and let the windows api detect if I compile for ASCII or wide chars. So I am not familiar with any side effects when compiling for unicode and then calling SetDlgItemTextA

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer: FWIK, UNICODE is the native mode of operation for the windows API. The ANSI API will internally be converted to UNICODE (saves flawed USER string conversions ? ,maybe).

Comment: BTW: some API functions are not in the ANSI flavoured API.

Comment: @PepijnKramer OP is using an `unsigned char` buffer, not `char`. Otherwise this would obviously work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Dang missed that completely :) . Changing the buffer to just `char` would be the easy fix.

Comment: Thanks everyone. My initial fix was to use `reinterpret_cast` and then I did ultimately go back and ask myself the question why was this buffer `unsigned char` in the first place. I realized that it did not need to be. So I've changed to `char` and all is good.